# Where do i get Secret ARN when running aws cli rds execute-statement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

trying to run an aws cli rds command to run a bit of sql to update a DB.  Using the following:

```
aws rds-data execute-statement \
    --resource-arn "arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:myaccountnumber:cluster:mysql-database" \
    --database "myDBname" \
    --sql "select * from configurations where configuration = 'mydb' and propertykey = 'environment';" 
    --secret-arn "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-west-2:123456789012:secret:mysecret"
```

I'm struggling to work out what the secret ARN is?

I get that it's something stored in secrets manager but do not know what this is from the RDS instance.

How do i set this on the instance or is it something like the user password?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Executing statements in your database via the AWS API only works (at this time) if your database is an Aurora Serverless cluster with the [Data API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-data-api-for-amazon-aurora-serverless/) enabled. To use the Data API you have to pass it an ARN to a secret that contains the database credentials.

Comment: thanks, any suggestions on way to execute a bit of sql after restoring a snapshot to a new instance for test and dev environment?  Looking for something to create users on restored instances